# Spray-painting simulation

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to simulate a spray painting, like pressing a “brushes” in the Microsoft “paint” program, with the left mouse.

In detail, when I push the left mouse, color is sprayed and its coating stroke is uniformed. The thickness is reflected through color intensity. I wonder if this can be done by Matlab toolbox, GUI, or do I need to use another software?
Thank for your help.

Comment: Cross-posted on MATLAB Answers: https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2061937-spray-painting-simulation-and-thickness-evaluation